Are you more likely to break a string when bending behind the nut of a guitar vs. when bending on the fretboard?
When I refer to 'bending behind the nut', I am referring to the action of fretting a note and then applying a downward force to one of the strings in the section labelled 'L1' in the image below to increase the pitch of the note being played
When I refer to 'bending on the fretboard', I am referring to the action of fretting a note and then pushing the string upwards across the fretboard to increase the pitch of the note being played
My logic is that the force being applied behind the nut is over a shorter length than the length over which force is being applied when bending across the fretboard, which results in higher stress per unit length, making it easier to break a string, but I would like someone to confirm/deny this and explain why this is the case.

From anecdotal experience you are correct: you have to push a lot harder beyond the nut because you have to bend the note with a vastly shorter length of string. This puts the string under a ton of tension.

For the benefit of non-guitar-playing physicists: what is "fretting a note", and which direction is upwards and downwards in this scenario?

From personal experience it's far easier for me to break a string by bending a note located halfway down the neck than it is for me to bend and break behind the nut. Bending behind the nut is no different than using the tuning pegs to increase/decrease tension

You need to determine the force necessary to deflect a string under tension: https://www.derek-hasted.co.uk/hago/faqs/formulae/

I believe you do risk breaking the string more by bending behind the nut of the guitar.
First off, some assumptions.  I assume you finger the fret in the L2 position at basically the same position in each case.  There will be a small-angle effect caused by bending in L2, because you are dragging it to a point along the fret that is further from the end of the string.  But that should be small.  Perhaps 5% (depends greatly on where in the string you do the bend).
This means I also get to assume that the tension on the part of the string from L2 to the pickups is what matters for determining pitch.  If you raise an A (440Hz) to an A# (466Hz), the tension has to be the same in both cases.
Tension in a string is the same everywhere, so if it takes 100N of tension to play an A#, it takes 100N everywhere on the string.  That is, of course, unless the nut provides a substantial amount of friction.  Instinctively this doesn't feel like the case for steel strings, but this might be non-trivial for nylon.  A quick test for this would be to tune the string up, increasing tension behind the nut, and then playing the string a few times.  If the pitch goes up when you do so, the added vibrations are helping equalize the tension across the string.  If it stays flat, then the low-friction assumption is probably a good one.
The factor that I think would play the largest part is the length of the string.  To increase the tension by some amount, you have to increase the length by some amount.  For any given angle of bend, the amount of length you will gain is proportional to the straight line length of the unbent string.  Bending at L2 bends a long string, so you only need to bend a small angle to increase the length meaningfully.  To increase the length the same amount at L1, you would have to bend it at a larger angle.
Guitar strings are resilient steel, but continued flexing at the same place at a large angle is more likely to introduce stress fractures at that point on the string.  That seems to be the most substantial difference between the two bending approaches.
